# Css childs of before & after

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-lists

Inside a ul I have 6 lis, I want to take the last 5 lis :before and :after

How do I get the childs of this (expect the first one):

```
nav li a:before, nav li a:after {
}
```

I tried this but did not work:

```
nav li:nth-child(n+5) a:before, nav li:nth-child(n+5) a:after {
    content:none; 
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to select is it the last 5 elements or everything except the last 5.

Comment: the last 5, so all except the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods to going about this. One way is to simply apply styles to the following:

```
nav li a:before, nav li a:after {
}
```

And then override those styles for just the first element:

```
nav li:first-child a:before, nav li:first-child a:after {
}
```

Or, you could use the :nth-last-child() selector to select all of the last 5 elements you need:

```
nav li:nth-last-child(-n+5) a:before, nav li:nth-last-child(-n+5) a:after {
}
```

The only issue with this approach is IE8 does not support :nth-last-child.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
   nav li:not(:first-child) a::before, 
   nav li:not(:first-child) a::after {
       /* your styles here */
    }
```

or

```
    nav ul li:nth-last-child(-n+5) {
           /* your styles here */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css like given below:

```
nav ul li:nth-child(5) a:before,
nav ul li:nth-child(5) a:after {
    content:.;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A quick update to suit:

```
nav ul li:nth-child(5) a:before,
nav ul li:nth-child(5) a:after {
    content:.;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes